# Amendig existing kql

Tags: azure, kql

Can you please have a look at my query below and try to assist me with this

```
// please add a list of your servers here, these ones are the ones that are *shutdown* overnight
let shutdownComputers = dynamic(["machines"]);
// always exclude these computers
let excludeComputers = dynamic(["machines"]);
// config the hours to exclude
let startHour = 1900; // 07:00 PM
let endHour = 06; // 06:00 Am
Heartbeat
// Get just the excluded Servers
| where TimeGenerated > startofday(ago(24h))
| where Computer in (shutdownComputers)
| summarize LastCall = arg_max( TimeGenerated, datetime_part("hour", TimeGenerated) between( startHour .. endHour) )
by Computer, sComputer = strcat("Computer goes offline between ", startHour," to ", endHour," :",Computer), ComputerEnvironment
| where isnotempty(LastCall)
| project Computer , LastCall, sComputer
// Now join those excluded servers with the others...
| join kind= fullouter
(
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > startofday(ago(24h))
| where Computer !in (shutdownComputers) and Computer !in(excludeComputers)
| summarize LastCall = arg_max(TimeGenerated,*) by Computer
) on Computer
// This bit can probably be improved if I get time
| extend Computer = iif(isempty(Computer),Computer1,Computer),
LastCall = iif(isempty(LastCall),LastCall1,LastCall)
| summarize by LastCall, Computer, sComputer
| where LastCall < ago(10m)
```

Azure VM's heartbeat alert not working as expected shown in the screenshot below.

There are some machines, which are not being reported.

First machine from the example net-ovuat2 is stopped and i am getting an alert, second    machine NET-P2PTESTAPP1. I have asked not to report about the machine  at certain period starting from 7:00pm but no alert for this one also  as the machine is switched off before 7:00pm.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGjRG.png)

Comment: can I please have a response on this

Comment: Hi Arslan, can you please clarify your question by providing data "inline the query" using datatable() operator? Also, please describe what behavior you would like to achieve.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by provide data "inline the query", there just the hostnames (server names). The behaviour , I am looking for, when any hostname, which gets turned off or not receiving any pings during the hours I have included. I should get an alert. Basically , I have asked to send me the alert , if the machine gets powered of anytime before 6:00pm